# UV coordinates scale with changes in object scale?

Tags: uv

Right now, scaling a textured object like this one:

[image: normal.png]

By a factor of 3 on the X axis, results in the following:

[image: normal_scaling.png]

I would like the same scaling operation to produce these results:

[image: wanted_scaling.png]

In other words: I want the UV coordinates, not the texture mapping in existing UVs, to scale with the change in object scale. I tried the UVproject modifier, but has it to be applied manually. I want the UV rescaling be done in a fully automatic way.

Is there a way to do that in blender?

Comment: Are UV coordinates a requirement? If not, try using generated coordinates. They should work fine for a simple plane.

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Internal render?

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, they must be UV coordinates. Also, the object in question could potentially be more complex (in the images I posted, it's a cube).

Comment: @MaxKielland Neither. I just want the UV coordinates to scale with the change in object scale, so I can get the desired result in the viewport.

Comment: Well, there is a quite big difference between Cycles and Blender Internal. The parameters for textures and UV mapping are located at different locations and Cycles don't support all features in Blender Internal 100% yet.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use Vertex Slide instead of scaling.
Select the vertices / edge you want to transform and hit <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to Vertex Slide. Move it to desired location and make sure you have Correct UVs checked in the options (left T panel).
You can use keyboard to set the exact value while sliding (I set `-3` in the video).

If you need to extend the vertices outside, start sliding and keep <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed.

[image: Vertex slide - making sure to check Correct UVs; Sliding and seting the desired extention by pressing 3- on keyboard; Extending the geometry by pressing Alt key while sliding]

Answer (score 0):

One fast solution can be: duplicate the object and hide the copy, add to the first object an UV warp modifier targeting from second to first.

Then scaling the object will not scale the textures.